# Is Minimax Linkage a Lance-Williams hierarchical clustering?

Tags: clustering, algorithms, proof, hierarchical-clustering

I found the following article on ["Hierarchical Clustering With Prototypes
via Minimax Linkage"](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jbien/jasa2011minimax.pdf).

It is stated in Property 6 that

> Minimax linkage cannot be written using [Lance–Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method) updates.

A succint proof using a counter-example is given:

> Proof. Figure 9 shows a simple one-dimensional example that could not
>   arise if minimax linkage followed Lance–Williams updates. The upper
>   and lower panels show two configurations of points for which the
>   right side of (4) is identical but the left side differs; in
>   particular, $d(G_1 \cup G_2,H) = 9$ for the upper panel, whereas
>   $d(G_1 \cup G_2,H) = 8$ for the lower panel.

But I do not understand their proof. For both cases (upper and lower panels), $d(G_1,H) = 16$, $d(G_2,H) = 7$, $d(G_1,G_2) = 5$.

I cannot see any reasons that $\alpha(G_2)$ in the first case must equal to $\alpha(G_2)$ in the second case as, for instance, $G_2$ has not the same cardinal.

Comment: Thank you for sharing an interesting article. I do not understand that thing, either just now, maybe because I've read only that small section so far. I believe that to understand one have to _follow their_ main algorithm (minimax) definitions an then to try to reproduce its results using the LW formula. They seem to say that the results will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they messed up the counter example.

Consider an additional point in the upper $G_2$ *left* of the center, so it loks like this: "X-X-X---X"

Are you then convinced of the proof?

I didn't completely study it yet (I think $O(n^3)$ or even $O(n^2)$ is too expensive), but that hotfix might be enough to help you?